# Roboguice, ADT 14+, and Android library projects

Tags: android, roboguice

Roboguice is such a neat little tool to tidy up boilerplate Android view code.

I loved using the `@InjectView` annotation so that I didn't have to initialize each and every view field in the onCreate() method of my Activities like this:

```
@InjectView(R.id.title) TextView title;
```

As part of Google's sweeping changes to library projects for ADT 14+ (which on the whole are a welcome improvement), id fields in generated R classes are no longer final.

So now when you want to use Roboguice inside of library projects, the `@InjectView` annotations no longer compile because annotations are processed at compile time, and `R.id.title` is no longer final.

Bummer...

Anybody else out there using Roboguice and have a creative workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Annotations supports a resource name based injection with a compile-time check.

https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Library-projects

Comment: Still annoying for refactoring support, but at least a compile time error would be generated!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you best bet is to follow this bug report on roboguice to see what kind of solution they come up with:
http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/issues/detail?id=139&sort=-id

Comment: I suppose there is just no workaround right now.  Unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

RoboGuice's recommendation is to replace the ID references by TAG ones instead: http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/LibraryProjects

Comment: Noted, although I would consider this unacceptably brittle against potential refactoring changes.

Comment: Agreed, any issues would be caught at runtime, in the consumer app. Ugh.

Comment: Agree, dont shoot the messenger, I did mention it was RoboGuice's own recommendation right? :)